# How can I add a nix package when using buildPythonPackage?

Tags: nix

#### The Python Part

I have a python application with multiple entrypoints, `json_out` and `json_in`.  I can run them both with this `default.nix`

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
(
  let jsonio = python37.pkgs.buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "jsonio";
    version = "0.0.1";
    src = ./.;
  };
  in python37.withPackages (ps: [ jsonio ])
).env
```

Like so:

```
$ nix-shell --run "json_out"
    { "a" : 1, "b", 2 }

$ nix-shell --run "echo { \"a\" : 1, \"b\", 2 } | json_in"
    keys: a,b
    values: 1,2
```

#### The System Part

I want to also invoke `jq` in the nix shell, like this:

```
$ nix-shell --run --pure "json_out | jq '.a' | json_in"
```

But I can't because it is not included.  I know that I can include jq into the nix shell using this `default.nix`

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "jsonio-environment";
  buildInputs = [ pkgs.jq ];
}
```

And it works on its own:

```
$ nix-shell --run --pure "echo { \"a\" : 1, \"b\", 2 } | jq '.a'"
    { "a" : 1 }
```

But now I don't have my application:

```
$ nix-shell --run "json_out | jq '.a'"
    /tmp/nix-shell-20108-0/rc: line 1: json_out: command not found
```

#### The Question

What default.nix file can I provide that will include both my application and the jq package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way to achieve this is to use `.overrideAttrs` to add additional dependencies to the environment like so:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
(
  let jsonio = python37.pkgs.buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "jsonio";
    version = "0.0.1";
    src = ./.;
  };
  in python37.withPackages (ps: [jsonio ])
).env.overrideAttrs (drv: {
  buildInputs = [ jq ];
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it out and it works.  What does `env` do and why does overriding `drv` to include `jq` cause it to be installed?   (sorry, I'm a nix noob)

Comment: Ah actually, the solution your posted is a very good alternative for when all you need is a nix-shell. `env` is just a convenience attribute so you can use it with nix-shell directly

Answer (score 1):

I needed to:

- provide the output of `buildPythonPackage` as part of the input of `mkDerivation`
- omit the `env`.  Based on a hint from an error message:

  > Python 'env' attributes are intended for interactive nix-shell
  >   sessions, not for building!

Here's what I ended up with:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

let jsonio_installed = (
  let jsonio_module = (
    python37.pkgs.buildPythonPackage rec {
      pname = "jsonio";
      version = "0.0.1";
      src = ./.;
    }
  );
  in python37.withPackages (ps: [jsonio_module ])
);
in stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "jsonio-environment";
  buildInputs = [ pkgs.jq jsonio_installed ];
}
```